# New VSIX project in VS2022 has XAML binding failures

Tags: visual-studio

### First time create a VS extension [VSIX] project in VS2022.

I do not know what is cause of problems below. I do everything like in doc.

I tried to run a simple VSIX project hello world in VS 2022 like in doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/extensibility-hello-world?view=vs-2022

**Step 1.**
Right-click the project (not the solution). On the context menu, select Add, and then New Item.

**Step 2.**
Select the Extensibility section, and then choose Command.

**Step 3.**
Press F5 to debug, check the XAML binding failures:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.Design;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Task = System.Threading.Tasks.Task;

namespace VSIXProject2 {
internal sealed class Command1 {
 public
 const int CommandId = 0x0100;

 public static readonly Guid CommandSet = new Guid("f83fb9b7-23b6-4605-bc93-74df2c22ec53");

 private readonly AsyncPackage package;

 private Command1(AsyncPackage package, OleMenuCommandService commandService) {
   this.package = package ??
     throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(package));
   commandService = commandService ??
     throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(commandService));

   var menuCommandID = new CommandID(CommandSet, CommandId);
   var menuItem = new MenuCommand(this.Execute, menuCommandID);
   commandService.AddCommand(menuItem);
 }

 public static Command1 Instance {
   get;
   private set;
 }

 private Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.IAsyncServiceProvider ServiceProvider {
   get {
     return this.package;
   }
 }

 public static async Task InitializeAsync(AsyncPackage package) {
   await ThreadHelper.JoinableTaskFactory.SwitchToMainThreadAsync(package.DisposalToken);

   OleMenuCommandService commandService = await package.GetServiceAsync(typeof (IMenuCommandService)) as OleMenuCommandService;
   Instance = new Command1(package, commandService);
 }

 private void Execute(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   ThreadHelper.ThrowIfNotOnUIThread();
   string message = string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "Inside {0}.MenuItemCallback()", this.GetType().FullName);
   string title = "Command1";

   VsShellUtilities.ShowMessageBox(
     this.package,
     message,
     title,
     OLEMSGICON.OLEMSGICON_INFO,
     OLEMSGBUTTON.OLEMSGBUTTON_OK,
     OLEMSGDEFBUTTON.OLEMSGDEFBUTTON_FIRST);
 }
}
}
```

System.Windows.Data Error: 17 : Cannot get 'CurrentState' value (type 'Int32') from '' (type 'PolicyBasedDataSource'). BindingExpression:Path=CurrentState; DataItem='PolicyBasedDataSource' (HashCode=8713795); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String') System.Windows.Data Error: 5 : Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property.; Value='' BindingExpression:Path=ToolTip; DataItem='GlyphButton' (Name='MaximizeButton'); target element is 'GlyphButton' (Name='MaximizeButton'); target property is 'Name' (type 'String') System.Windows.Data Error: 5 : Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property.; Value='' BindingExpression:Path=ToolTip; DataItem='GlyphButton' (Name='CloseButton'); target element is 'GlyphButton' (Name='CloseButton'); target property is 'Name' (type 'String') System.Windows.Data Error: 5 : Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property.; Value='' BindingExpression:Path=Content; DataItem='Button' (Name=''); target element is 'Button' (Name=''); target property is 'Name' (type 'String') System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Text' property not found on 'object' ''DataSource' (HashCode=60105532)'. BindingExpression:Path=Text; DataItem='DataSource' (HashCode=60105532); target element is 'VsToolBar' (Name=''); target property is 'Name' (type 'String') System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Items' property not found on 'object' ''DataSource' (HashCode=60105532)'. BindingExpression:Path=Items; DataItem='DataSource' (HashCode=60105532); target element is 'VsToolBar' (Name=''); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable') System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'PlacementSlot' property not found on 'object' ''DataSource' (HashCode=60105532)'. BindingExpression:Path=PlacementSlot; DataItem='DataSource' (HashCode=60105532); target element is 'VsToolBar' (Name=''); target property is 'Band' (type 'Int32') System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'BandIndex' property not found on 'object' ''DataSource' (HashCode=60105532)'. BindingExpression:Path=BandIndex; DataItem='DataSource' (HashCode=60105532); target element is 'VsToolBar' (Name=''); target property is 'BandIndex' (type 'Int32') System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'IsVisible' property not found on 'object' ''DataSource' (HashCode=60105532)'. BindingExpression:Path=IsVisible; DataItem='DataSource' (HashCode=60105532); target element is 'VsToolBar' (Name=''); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')

I found similar problem here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/new-vsix-project-in-vs2022-has-xaml-binding-failur/1580267?viewtype=solutions